# Passing a callback from module A to B with bound this, still has scope of B. Using babel

Tags: javascript, scope, webpack, babeljs, es6-promise

How come if I pass this 'test' function from module A to module B:

```
 //A.js
import B from './B'
export default {
    self: this,
    test: ()=> {
        console.log(self === this)  // this should return true but doesn't because when B calls it, "this" is B
    },
    initA:function() {
        B.initB(this.test); // b is undefined here
    }
};

//B.js
export default {
  callback: null,
  initB: function (func) {
    callback = func;
  },
  startTest: function () {
    this.callback();
  }
};
```

that the scope of `this` is still B when I run callback() in B.js? Also doesn't work if I make this function an arrow function.

I have created a repo demonstrating this issue:

https://github.com/es6Test/babel-test

hopefully someone with experience of this will be able to give a quick and easy solution.

Comment: Can you please add how you are importing `A.js` code and clean up the formatting? I find it difficult to read your question due to invalid JavaScript code. It would also help if you could provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MarkSimulacrum sorry for the delay, please see my edit:))

Comment: Can you provide an expected result, and the current result? Much of your code doesn't seem to make much sense to me: for example, all of the `this` statements in module `A.js` are `undefined` when used as they are.

Comment: please check this issue: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1359 @MarkSimulacrum

Comment: @MarkSimulacrum I created a repo for this specifically, thanks for any help: https://github.com/es6Test/babel-test

Comment: When I run `dist.js` I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: this.callback is not a function`. Is this the error that you're referring to in your question?

Comment: you run index.html @katranci

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a statically-declared lambda at the top level of an ES6 module, where there is no surrounding `this` for it to bind to. You're never explicitly `bind`ing the function, so the value of `this` should be undefined. It looks like Babel, while transpiling, is not providing a binding to force undefined and you end up with the previous `this`.

There appears to be some confusion as to the object literal with arrow function. Arrow functions take the `this` value of the surrounding scope when they were declared; object literals *do not* count as a scope, so the arrow function will not bind to the object.

If you want to bind the callback, you could simply change your `A` module to:

```
export default {
  self: this,
  makeTest: function () {
    return () => {
      console.log(self === this)
    };
  },
  initA: ()=> {
    B.initB(this.makeTest());
  }
};
```

and it should start working. As you can see, the arrow function is now within a real method that is invoked on the object.

You also have a tangential problem where your `import 'B'` line is meant to import the `./B.js` file, but is actually looking for `node_modules/B/[entrypoint].js` (even with webpack involved).

Comment: sheesh thats impressive thought process! and quick